# I am slice a string from a text file and put it into an array, however whenever I output the array they are filled with 0's

Tags: arrays, vb.net, file

My code basically inputs 3 random variables into a text file, with a ":" separating each variable. And the second part of my code basically reads the text file again, and slices the string to get the 2nd variable using the MID function that I input previously and adds it into an array. However when I output the array, it's full of 0s. I tried figuring out what's wrong but I don't know.

Here is my code:

```
Dim r1, r2, r3, counter, counter1, counter2, sep As Integer
Dim line As String
Dim middleline(20)
line = ""
counter1 = 0
sep = 0
FileSystem.FileOpen(1, "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\binarysearch.txt", OpenMode.Output, OpenAccess.Write)
For counter = 1 To 20
    If Rnd() = 0.21 Then
        r1 = -1
    Else
        Do
            r1 = Rnd() * 100
        Loop Until r1 <= 20
    End If
    Do
        r2 = Rnd() * 100
    Loop Until r2 >= 10 AndAlso r2 <= 50
    If Rnd() = 0.21 Then
        r3 = -1
    Else
        Do
            r3 = Rnd() * 100
        Loop Until r3 <= 20
    End If
    line = r1 & ":" & r2 & ":" & r3
    FileSystem.WriteLine(1, line)
Next
Console.WriteLine("Generated successfully.")

For counter = 1 To 20
    middleline(counter) = 0
Next

For counter = 1 To 20
    FileSystem.PrintLine(1, line)
    For counter1 = 1 To Len(line)
        If Mid(line, 1, counter1) = ":" Then
            sep += 1
        End If
        If sep = 1 Then
            middleline(counter2) = middleline(counter2) & Mid(line, 1, counter1)
            counter2 += counter2
        End If
    Next
Next

For counter = 1 To 20
    Console.WriteLine(middleline(counter))
Next
Console.WriteLine(middleline)
```

Comment: Well, in the second part of the program, you are NOT READING anything from the file. You're using [FileSystem.PrintLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.printline?view=net-8.0), which "Writes display-formatted data to a sequential file." You probably want [FileSystem.LineInput()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.lineinput?view=net-8.0) instead...

Comment: After you create the file in the first half, you should close it completely and then re-open in READ mode so you can subsequently read all the lines from the beginning of the file.

Comment: The `FileOpen()` api exists only for backwards compatibility when porting forward old code and **should not be used** for new development.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure where your code goes wrong, but I have given it a little rewrite and this appears to be working ok.

I changed the random number generation as I felt your loop was a little heavy duty.

Also switched the file handling to newer methods.

```
    Private Shared RndGenMachine As Random = New Random

    Public Sub DoWork(FileName As String)

        Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer
        Dim middleline As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        'build the initial file
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(FileName, True)

            For counter As Integer = 1 To 20

                r1 = RndGenMachine.Next(0, 20)
                r3 = RndGenMachine.Next(0, 20)
                r2 = RndGenMachine.Next(10, 50)

                Dim line As String = $"{r1}:{r2}:{r3}"
                sw.WriteLine(line)

            Next

        End Using

        Console.WriteLine("Generated successfully.")

        'read it back for parsing
        Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String) = File.ReadLines(FileName)

        For lineCounter = 0 To lines.Count - 1

            Dim splits() As String = lines(lineCounter).Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))
            middleline.Add(splits(1))

        Next

        For Each middlelinevalue As String In middleline
            Console.WriteLine(middlelinevalue)
        Next

    End Sub
```

If you'd prefer to use the old style file handler, you can try something like this:

```
    Public Sub DoWorkOldStyle(FileName As String, iterations As Integer)

        Console.WriteLine("Starting generation...")

        Dim r1, r2, r3 As Integer

        'build the initial file
        FileSystem.FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Output, OpenAccess.Write)

        For counter As Integer = 1 To iterations

            r1 = RndGenMachine.Next(0, 20)
            r3 = RndGenMachine.Next(0, 20)
            r2 = RndGenMachine.Next(10, 50)

            Dim line As String = $"{r1}:{r2}:{r3}"
            FileSystem.WriteLine(1, line)

        Next

        FileSystem.FileClose(1)

        Console.WriteLine("Generated successfully. Starting evaluation...")

        'read it back for parsing
        FileSystem.FileOpen(1, FileName, OpenMode.Input, OpenAccess.Read)

        Dim middleline As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        While Not EOF(1)

            Dim line As String = LineInput(1)
            Dim splits() As String = line.Split(Convert.ToChar(":"))
            middleline.Add(splits(1))

        End While

        FileClose(1)

        For Each middlelinevalue As String In middleline
            Console.WriteLine(middlelinevalue)
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("Evalutaion complete.")

    End Sub
```

Comment: The reading would be tidier as something like `For Each line In File.ReadLines(FileName)`, IMHO. If you get `lines.Count` then it has to read the whole file in one go instead of only using the memory for one line at a time.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for your input my almost namesake. I often do the full read up front if I know I'm intending to process everything. It is a one-and-done on the reading so that it is out the way. But no fault with your suggestion, top class as usual. Thanks

Comment: You could use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines) if you want to explicitly read all the lines in one go. [*my almost namesake* - yes, sometimes I avoid adding comments elsewhere so as to avoid confusing people lol.]

Comment: @AndrewMorton for the size of the file I would consider ReadAllLines and ReadLines to be interchangable. If it came down to an intense and regular process I'd probably do some benchmarking to work out which one suited the specific scenario. Thanks again for the comments. Find me at my email address in the profile if so inclined.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much however I do not know how to use streamwriter and our instructor has only taught us the other method, is it possible you could implement it in the other method as I only partly understand your code.